# Is there a marketplace for research/ideas grants?

Tags: research-process, funding

Non-academic here. Bachelors in Computer Science.

My question is, how does research happen? Is there some sort of directory/marketplace/dating-app where researchers and funders can meet each other ?

I'm envisioning something like:

1. Dr. Bob wants to study fruit flies.
2. Nestle wants to know how to keep fruit flies out of their factories.
3. Some tool helps Dr. Bob and Nestle meet up and do some research.

Is that how the research world works?

Comment: If only getting funding was as easy as swiping right on Tinder...

Comment: Pivot attempts to play this broker role. Having a well-edited list of available grants attracts scholars to the site, but getting the scholars to interact with each other for new collaborations is tricky. https://pivot.cos.com/

Comment: In the EU especially, you often need to partner with a dozen other EU countries to get the big money. I always wondered how that happened in practice, as it seems a monumental achievement to coordinate so many different people. 

I know found one answer: my university has a team of people who do that for a job. They attend so-called "match-making" events where researchers pitch their ideas to other academics and industry partners.

Comment: @cactus_pardner "getting the scholars to interact with each other for new collaborations is tricky" Why? What it the motivation to not collaborate ?

Comment: The short answer is, collaboration is hard. :) I commented rather than answering because the broad part of the question is that most academics find funding from the same (often government, sometimes nonprofit) sources their professors did.